# Testing Java Methods

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

Okay, so I am interviewing for a company and they want me to complete some exercises. The logic I can figure out. Only thing is Ive never worked with IntelliJ, AndroidStudio, or Gradle and it seems I need to use them. Here is the clone url to the project: https://github.com/Mobilgov/interview.git

If you're familiar with AndroidStudio/IntelliJ and Gradle, then see if you can open the project and run the method within "interview/problems/src/test/java/com/payit/problems/Problem2Test.java", for example.

Ultimately, Im just trying to test the logic within some Java files.

If I can just figure out how to run these tests, then I can whip out the logic in the actual problems real quick!

Thanks!

Comment: "Build and Run Android Studio Java App" - Do you want to run the Junit tests, or build and run the reactive-native app?  Your title and actual question contradict each other.  For the first you only need a JVM to run the Junit tests as they are nothing to do with running the app on a Android device/Android Runtime.

Comment: Junit tests I suppose. I was instructed to fill in the methods with logic, so I need only test those classes. Ultimately I will compress it and send the project back to them. initially i checked out with v-control into intellij and it kept telling me I needed Android SDK, which led me to using android studio bc people were saying intellij android sdk was deprecated

Answer (score 0):

This job interview must be prepared to resolve such a liquefaction

Here are some tips I can give you:
You can get a ready-to-install Gradel application and install the latest version of Android Sdk
However, change the file to the sequence of folder names or change the names of the folders respectively to obtain the name of the file in the folders
Now open the project from the Android Studio or any platform you like

Comment: To clarify my question, how do I run my application within Android Studio? I have no run configurations yet, where do i begin?

Comment: Search in Githp for any simple project and replace the folder app> src